# Grunt command has no effect : no output no error

Tags: gruntjs, ubuntu-14.04

04).

I want to use grunt. 
I install grunt following this http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
I also installed nodejs.

But when i type the command grunt -h it has no effect and just a new line for a new command !

I try to remove nodejs it output a error like. grunt  is not recognize..

Any idea to debug that ?

Many thanks !

Comment: I do have search about my problem my question seem oblivious for me.. Let me know if something missing... i m new user on ubuntu. so help would be really appreciate !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a problem with my node installation I did:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

and it solve my problem!